# Clarity stack-view does not work with Angular ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I have to display key-value pairs with [Clarity's stack-view](https://clarity.design/documentation/stack-view) in the same component multiple times.
To avoid code duplication I would like to use `ng-template` and `ngTemplateOutlet`.

Unfortunately the outer `clr-stack-block` is only expandable if it contains an additional `clr-stack-block` element with static content besides the `ngTemplateOutlet`.

Please have a look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-angular-7-2ue7wd

The app.component.html contains my sample code and showcases that the outer `clr-stack-block` is only expandable if it contains an additional static element.

```html
<ng-template #propertyList let-obj="obj" let-props="props">
    <clr-stack-block *ngFor="let prop of props">
        <clr-stack-label>{{prop}}</clr-stack-label>
        <clr-stack-content>{{ !obj[prop] ? '-' : obj[prop] }}</clr-stack-content>
    </clr-stack-block>
</ng-template>

<clr-stack-view>
    <clr-stack-block [clrSbExpanded]="true">
        <clr-stack-label>not expandable - but why?</clr-stack-label>

        <!-- don't use a 'ng-container' here as it will break the stack view -->
        <clr-stack-block
            *ngTemplateOutlet="propertyList; context: {obj: {name: 'John Doe', birthdate: '01. Jan 1970'}, props: ['name', 'birthdate']}">
        </clr-stack-block>
    </clr-stack-block>
    <clr-stack-block [clrSbExpanded]="true">
        <clr-stack-label>expandable - because of additional static block element?</clr-stack-label>

        <clr-stack-block
            *ngTemplateOutlet="propertyList; context: {obj: {name: 'Test User', birthdate: '10. Feb 2000'}, props: ['name', 'birthdate']}">
        </clr-stack-block>

        <clr-stack-block>
            <clr-stack-label><i>static</i></clr-stack-label>
            <clr-stack-content><i>clr-stack-block</i></clr-stack-content>
        </clr-stack-block>
    </clr-stack-block>
</clr-stack-view>
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stackview tries to auto-detect if there are stackblock children, but if it fails to do so you can use the [clrSbExpandable] input to explicitly specify if or when expandable behavior should be enabled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Adding `[clrSbExpandable]="true"` does indeed solve the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems a clarity bug.

1 workaround that I found is that you can add a static block with CSS property to display: none. That way it won't show up and you still get it working till a fix is provided on the clarity side. I also advise you to create an issue on their github Here is a stackblitz example:

https://clarity-angular-7-jaubxg.stackblitz.io